# which xaml control to use for displaying pdf file using itextsharp?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

I need to display the pdf as it is, with all content texts and images both. I am trying to render it using itextsharp. But don't know which control to use for displaying the content.

Also provide me with any sample code, if you have.

I tried existing sample code on web, but that returns only text.
If you can suggest any other free api's, it will be appreciated. I am developing app for windows store, so i need it to be WIN RT compatible.

I am using c# and xaml language.

Thanks in Advance!!!!